# Failed to install App on device. (with maps api)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I get this error when i try to install my app from eclipse on my htc magic.

Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!

Logcat says:
at.tomtasche.altitude requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!

I developed an app with google maps before and there it works fine.
And yes i have the

> uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"

in the application tag of my manifest. It also works in the emulator, just my device dont install it.

Comment: Do you have the original ROM, or a modded ROM? More specifically, does the regular Google Maps application exist and work on your Magic?

Comment: Yes i have CM6.1 RC1 but i installed the Google Addon and Map, Navigation, etc. works fine.

Comment: Were you able to install it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this sample Google Maps project.](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/) If it gives the same symptoms, then your phone does not support Google Maps properly.

OTOH, if the sample project works, then you can perhaps identify what the differences are that are causing it to work and your project not.